# checkboxes and buttons enable

Tags: javascript, checkbox, disabled-control

I have two checkboxes, and two buttons below them:

```
<tr>
  <form ACTION="jspCheckBox.jsp">
    SC Information Received  <input type="checkbox"  value="SC Information received">   
    Validation Begun <input type="checkbox"  value="Validate">
  </form>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="middle" align="left" style="padding-left:10px;" nowrap>
    <button type="button" class="btn" name="btnApprove" onclick="approve();">Approve</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn" name="btnDeny" onclick="deny();">Deny</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

When the page is first opened, the first checkbox should be enabled, but the other checkbox and both buttons should be disabled.

Subsequently, when the user checks the first checkbox, the first checkbox should become disabled and the second checkbox should become enabled. (The buttons should remain disabled at this point.)

Lastly, when the user checks the second checkbox, the second checkbox should become disabled and both buttons should become enabled.

Obviously this requires JavaScript.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)